# Llenar un vector con los datos de un archivo.txt

Tags: java

tengo una clase Llamada Gun, la cual tiene como atributos dos enteros y u string, quisiera hacer un vector de tipo Gun y que cada posicion se llene con los datos de un archivo por ejemplo 
que el archivo .txt contenga:

```
25,20,Pistol
```

entonces que la posicion 0 el primer entero reciba 25, el segundo 20, y el el string "pistol".

si es posible? gracias de antemano

Comment: Es posible, pero ¿Cuál es el código actual que utilizas para llenar el 'vector'?

Comment: hola, en realidad no tengo un codigo aun, no pido que me lo hagan quisiera quizas una explicacion del funcionanmiento de eso que Si es posible para yo poder implementarlo, gracias

Comment: Pues, lo que buscas se llama `Split()`, hay maneras mas comodas y practicas de hacerlo, asumo que tienes un archivo con 3 columnas por fila, delimitado por `,` [Java String.split() method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm) está en ingles, intenta algo para partir la cadena y veremos como te ayudamos!

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que tienes una clase como la siguiente:

```
class Gun {
  int A, B;
  String C;

  public Gun(int A, int B, String C) {
    this.A = A;
    this.B = B;
    this.C = C;
  }

  //////// Éstos son métodos auxiliares, ignorar.
  // Constructor para prueba
  public Gun(String[] line) {
    this.A = Integer.parseInt(line[0]);
    this.B = Integer.parseInt(line[1]);
    this.C = line[2];
  }

  // Método para obtener la representación en string
  // del objeto...
  public String getText(){
    return A + "," + B + "," + C;
  }
}
```

Una forma, de las varias que existen, de escribir y leer texto de/a un archivo es la siguiente:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
  // El "vector" de guns
  List<Gun> guns = new ArrayList() {{
      add(new Gun(1, 1, "A"));
      add(new Gun(2, 2, "B"));
      // ...
  }};

  // Escribir a un archivo
  try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("guns.txt", "UTF-8")) {
    guns.forEach(gun -> writer.println(gun.getText()));
  } catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
  }

  guns.clear();

  // Leer de ese mismo archivo
  try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("guns.txt"))) {
    for (String s = in.readLine(); s != null; s = in.readLine())
      guns.add(new Gun(s.split(",")));
  } catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
  }

  guns.forEach(gun -> System.out.println("Gun: " + gun.getText()));
}
```

---

Si lo que te interesa es salvar la información de tus objetos, otra posible solución seria serializar.